# Choosing $100$ numbers in which one of the chosen number is divisible by another one

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove that if $100$ integers are chosen from $1,2, \ldots, 200$, and one
>   of the integers chosen is less than $15$, then there are two chosen
>   numbers such that one of them is divisible by the other.

---

It is a classic exercise in combinatorics. For the answer, please refer to [Choose 100 numbers from 1~200 (one less than 16) - prove one is divisible by another!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181609/choose-100-numbers-from-1200-one-less-than-16-prove-one-is-divisible-by-ano%22Choose%20100%20numbers%20from%201~200%20(one%20less%20than%2016)%20-%20prove%20one%20is%20divisible%20by%20another!%22). I want to move forward and ask something more. First, let me rephrase the question:

> $100$ integers are chosen from $1,2, \ldots, 200$. Let $n$ be the
>   smallest number of these chosen numbers. Prove that if $n=1,2,\ldots,
>  15$, then two chosen numbers can be found such that one of them is
>   divisible by the other.

---

Now my question is:

> Find all possible $n$.

This question comes to my mind when I first encounter this exercise. I was curious that why we should have the condition 'less than 16'. What if I change it to 'less than 17'? Does it mean that if $n=16$, it would be possible for me to find a counterexample? Of course, $n$ cannot be too large, as if $n=101$, then the chosen numbers would be $101, 102, \ldots, 200$ and none of them is a multiple of the others. So, I get the sense that some values of $n$ work, while some don't. So I post here to gather your opinions.

By the way, I cannot prove or disprove the statement when $n=16$. I think the idea to prove or disprove this case would help understand more about my ultimate questions.

> $100$ integers are chosen from $1,2, \ldots, 200$. Let $n$ be the
>   smallest number of these chosen numbers.
>
> Prove or disprove: If $n=16$, then two chosen numbers can be found
>   such that one of them is divisible by the other.

My attempt to construct a counterexample:

- I noticed that no two numbers in the set $\{101, 102, \ldots, 200\}$ divides each other. So, I started with this set and added in $16$.
- Then I had to remove $112, 128, 144, 160, 176, 192$.
- I needed to add in some new numbers, but I then would need to, again, remove many more existing numbers. So I think it is getting nowhere....
- Think in another direction: Start with an empty set. Add in the smallest number $16$. Then all the multiple of $16$ cannot be in the set.
- Add in another number, say $17, 18, \ldots, 31$. Wait... Then I cannot add in anymore numbers...

I welcome any comments and suggestions.

Comment: If you read the accepted answer, you know that you need to be careful with what pigeon holes you choose, you can't just start off with all the numbers above $100$. That being said, it's entirely possible that the $16$ was not a real limit to the problem, but rather the limit as to where a pigeon hole proof stops being practical.

Answer (score 0):

There is a counterexample for the case where the condition is a number chosen is less than or equal to $16$. It is built on the ideas found in the question link and another similar question:

- [Choose 100 numbers from 1~200 (one less than 16) - prove one is divisible by another!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181609/choose-100-numbers-from-1200-one-less-than-16-prove-one-is-divisible-by-ano%22Choose%20100%20numbers%20from%201~200%20(one%20less%20than%2016)%20-%20prove%20one%20is%20divisible%20by%20another!%22)
- [Each number in a subset $S\subseteq \{1,\ldots,2n\}$ does not divide another one. Then $\max |S|$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409234/each-number-in-a-subset-s-subseteq-1-ldots-2n-does-not-divide-another-one/1409402)

### Prove that at most $100$ numbers can be selected

Form descending 2-sequences (these are the pigeonholes) starting with each term in $T=\{101,102,\ldots,199,200\}$, where each sequence is finite and ends on an odd term and the term in any sequence is the previous term divided by $2$. Denote each sequence by its starting term (note that $n=100$), e.g.
$$\begin{array}{rll}
S_{2n}&=(2n,n,\ldots)&=(200,100,50,25) \\ 
S_{2n-1}&=(2n-1)     &=(199)\\  
&\quad\vdots \\
S_{n+2}&=\{n+2,\ldots\}&=(102,51)  \\
S_{n+1}&=\{n+1,\ldots\}&=(101)
\end{array}$$

Every number in $\{1,2,\ldots,2n\}$ appears in exactly one of the $S_{k}$ because:

1. *Surjective*. Every number inclusively between $1$ and $n$ has a multiple of a power of two inclusively between $n+1$ and $2n$. If not, $2 \ge \frac{2n+1}{n}$, which is absurd.
2. *Injective*. No number can appear in more than one sequence. If this was untrue we could find two distinct terms in $\{n+1,n+2,\ldots,2n\}$, one of which is a multiple (of a power of two) of the other.

It is clear that every pair of terms in a given $S_{k}$ has the smaller term dividing the larger one, so we can choose at most one term from each $S_{k}$.
To construct a counterexample, we need to choose exactly one from each, and ensure that $16$ is included.

### Sketch of the counteraxample P

When $n$ is odd, $S_n={n}$ has only one element, so this must be chosen. Hence, we need that $P$ contains every odd integer between $100$ and $200$, i.e. 
$$P_1=\{101,103,105,\ldots,199\}$$

This eliminates all submultiples so for the elements that cannot be chosen:
$$Q_1=\{1,3,5,\ldots,65\}$$

For each odd number $n$ in $\{67,69,\ldots,99\}$ the relevant sequence is $S_n=(2n,n)$. It is less restrictive to choose $n$ than $2n$, since all further multiples of $n$ exceed $200$, and the submultiples of $n$ are a subset of those of 2n$. So choose

$$P_2=\{67,69,71,\ldots,99\}$$

This choice eliminates all numbers that are twice these:

$$Q_2=\{134,138,142,\ldots,198\}$$

Then for every large enough $n$ that is a multiple of $3$ in $P_1$ (and $4n>200$), the number $2n$ needs to be chosen (since $n,4n$ and higher multiples are excluded). So then

$$P_3=\{102,106,110,\ldots,130\}$$

The eliminated submultiples are:

$$Q_3=\{2,6,10,14,18,22,26,34,38,42\}$$

Now consider all even numbers at least $100$ that are not in $Q_2$ or $P_3$, a typical case is $196$ for which $S_{196}=(196,98,49)$ i.e. with an odd third number that is in $Q_1$. By an argument similar to that used before, it is preferable to choose the smaller of the two even numbers. This gives

$$P_4=\{50,54,58,62,66,68,70,74,76,78,82,84,86,90,94,98\}$$

which excludes the further multiples

$$Q_4=\{100,108,116,124,132,136,140,148,152,156,164,168,172,180,188,196,200\}$$

and additionally

$$Q_5=\{4,28,30\}$$

We are left with the disjoint 2-sequences (where entries that cannot be selected are removed), where one number must be chosen from each to make up the full quota of $100$:

$$\begin{array}{cllll}
S_{128}'&=(128,64,32,16,8) & & S_{192}'&=(192,96,48,24,12) \\
S_{160}'&=(160,80,40,20) & & S_{144}'&=(144,72,36) \\
S_{184}'&=(184,92,46) & & S_{176}'&=(176,88,44) \\
S_{120}'&=(120,60) & & S_{112}'&=(112,56) \\
S_{104}'&=(104,52) \\
\end{array}$$

In addition, the numbers $8,12,20$ cannot be selected without preventing any selection from another 2-sequence. Hence

$$\begin{array}{clcllcll}
S_{128}''&=(128,64,32,16) & & S_{192}''&=(192,96,48,24) & & S_{160}''&=(160,80,40) 
\end{array}$$

So it turns out that the following set is selectable as there are no pairwise multiples:

$$P_5=\{16,24,36,40,44,46,52,56,60\}$$

### Resulting counterexample

Putting everything together a possible counterexample is:

$\begin{array}{ll}
P&=P_1\cup P_2\cup P_3\cup P_4\cup P_5 \\
 &=\{67,69,71,\ldots,199,\color{blue}{16},24,36,40,44,46,\\
 &\quad 50,52,\ldots,62,66,68,70,74,76,78,82,84,86,90,94,98, \\
 &\quad 102,106,110,\ldots,130 \}
\end{array}$

$P$ contains $67$ odd numbers and $33$ even numbers, with the odd numbers being on average larger than the even numbers. This should not be major surprise.